# ".local" suffix on local server (Manjaro)

Tags: dns, localhost, local, tld

I recently changed my Linux distribution (Manjaro) and my local domains defined in `/etc/hosts` and ending in `.local` no longer work.

```
# /etc/hosts
# Host addresses
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.0.1  hello.local
127.0.0.1  hello.domain.local
127.0.0.1  hello.other
```

```sh
$ ping hello.local
ping: hello.local: Nom ou service inconnu

$ ping hello.other
PING hello.other (127.0.0.1) 56(84) octets de données.
64 octets de localhost (127.0.0.1) : icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 temps=0.012 ms
...

$ ping hello.domain.local
PING hello.domain.local (127.0.0.1) 56(84) octets de données.
64 octets de localhost (127.0.0.1) : icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 temps=0.012 ms
...
```

This doesn't work only with a sub-domain of the tld .local : `hello.local`.

If it's a sub-sub domain : `hello.domain.local` , it works.

Also if the tld is not (.local) but .other : `hello.other`, it works.

where did I miss something?

Comment: Don't use `local` as a TLD, as it is reserved for `mDNS`.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, backup your **nsswitch.conf** ->
sudo  cp /etc/nsswitch.conf /etc/nsswitch.conf.bk

Then, goo to /etc/nsswitch.conf and

replace this line

**hosts: mymachines mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] files myhostname dns**

to

**hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns**

Comment: I simply put "files" as first hosts option and it works. Ex: hosts: files mymachines ....